How to remap right shift to backslash in Ubuntu 24.04?
How to remap R.Shift to slash ('/') in Ubuntu 24.04?
I want to remap R.Shift to '/' and L.Shift + R.Shift to '?'. I tried to use Input Remapper, Tweak, and XModMap, but their mappings do not work for terminals from some reason. I wonder if anyone has a solution for this.
In the case of xmodmap, it works outside the terminal, but not inside the terminal.

I have configured my Input Remapper to achieve your desired output inside and outside the terminal. Here are the keybindings and configurations that I have used:
For "/"(slash):

For "?"(question mark):

Also, don't forget to set the Autoload to "ON" after applying your presets.

Thanks very much, it works. I am using Ubuntu 24.04, and as for the target, I typed in "KEY_SLASH" instead of "slash". If I do this, the question mark also works without the additional preset rule.
